# hierarchical clustering in MapReduce to implement a dendrogram of representative link communities

Tags: java, mapreduce, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-data, dendrogram

I want to use  hierarchical clustering with a similarity between links to build
a dendrogram where each leaf is a link from the original network and branches represent link
communities using hierarchical clustering in MapReduce. Any references approaches algorithms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical clustering will not work well with MapReduce *ever*.

First of all, MapReduce is *designed* to process one record at a time, whereas distance computations *do* need at least two records at a time. Hacking distance based algorithms into MapReduce usually is a bad idea for this very reason; and this is why MapReduce is pretty much yesterdays news now. Nobody focuses on MapReduce anymore, it is too limited for anything except preprocessing and filtering.

Furthermore, it will not help much. The reason why hierarchical clustering scales inherently bad is that it requires `O(n^2)` memory and `O(n^3)` runtime in the usual implementation.
So any gains obtained by a distributed implementation will only allow you to process a marginally larger data set: if you add 8 times as many computers, you can only process a 2 times larger data set. This is clearly unsatisfactory for scalability. Plus, you will also need a lot more diskspace. Do you really expect to have `O(n^2)` disk space available?

Last but not least, if you really have big data, *you will not be able to look at the dendrogram anyway*.

**If you have big data, use a different algorithm. Or sampling.**

If your data isn't that large, just use a single-host implementation like [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), which is reasonably fast. Most likely, it will outperform a cluster-based implementation because it can avoid all the extra disk-IO you get with mapreduce.

Comment: First of all I very much appreciate your reply and agree with you on most points. I am looking at Petabyte to Exabytes of data. I am also open to Apache Spark which reduces disk I/O and a Storm NOSQL hybrid. I am constrained to these environments. Could you provide me further guidance? Thanks very much!

Comment: Furthermore, can ELKI be used in a parallel environment. I have sufficient memory available. for O(n^2) disk space available.

Comment: My goal is to perform line graphs link partitions and overlapping communities using a multiplicity of techniques and am looking for related cluster algorithms, techniques, and practices.

Comment: going with GraphX on Spark seems a way to go ... Any established algorithms methods etc?